# I can't edit post with image attachment using Trix Editor in Rails 5

Tags: json, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, trix

I'm using the gem `trix`.  I've followed a tutorial online for uploading images to the editor.  The image upload and storage works fine; however, when I go back to edit the post the trix-editor control doesn't show anything.  As if it is a blank post.  I also notice the following error in my console window of my browser but can't track down why it's happening.

```
VM931:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at v (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:19)
    at g.processElement (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:19)
    at g.processNode (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:19)
    at g.parse (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:19)
    at Function.g.parse (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:19)
    at Function.c.fromHTML (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:20)
    at t.loadHTML (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:21)
    at new a (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:21)
    at HTMLElement.attachedCallback (trix.self-e0bc0a706de91177cd7d3cf457cc5cabf40fb5662c3e1fed55c0fbc56ca16e69.js?body=1:22)
```

I can post any of the code you'd like, I'll try and include what I think is helpful below.  I've also totally stripped out Turbolinks from the application thinking that maybe it was effecting it, but I saw the same results.

**Here's the post's "body" value that isn't showing when using trix-editor**

*The form for the body attribute displays on the screen but it is blank*

```
<div>test<a href="/uploads/store/2cb381937ab8639f84b9ab32cfad1210.jpg" data-trix-attachment="{"contentType":"image/jpeg","filename":"3-sidesitting.jpg","filesize":67635,"height":453,"href":"/uploads/store/2cb381937ab8639f84b9ab32cfad1210.jpg","url":"/uploads/store/2cb381937ab8639f84b9ab32cfad1210.jpg","width":680}" data-trix-content-type="image/jpeg" data-trix-attributes="{"caption":"Yesssss I think it worked!"}"><figure class="attachment attachment--preview attachment--jpg"><img src="/uploads/store/2cb381937ab8639f84b9ab32cfad1210.jpg" width="680" height="453"><figcaption class="attachment__caption attachment__caption--edited">Yesssss I think it worked!</figcaption></figure></a></div>
```

**assets/javascript/application.js**

```
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require trix
//= require_tree .
```

**assets/javascript/trix-uploads.coffee**

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->

  uploadAttachment = (attachment) ->
    csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    file = attachment.file
    form = new FormData
    endpoint = '/images'
    form.append 'Content-Type', file.type
    form.append 'image[image]', file
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.open 'POST', endpoint, true
    xhr.setRequestHeader 'X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken

    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) ->
      progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100
      attachment.setUploadProgress progress

    xhr.onload = ->
      if @status >= 200 and @status < 300
        data = JSON.parse(@responseText)
        return attachment.setAttributes(
          url: data.url
          href: data.url)
      return

    xhr.send form

  Trix.config.attachments.preview.caption =
    name: false
    size: false
  document.addEventListener 'trix-attachment-add', (event) ->
    attachment = event.attachment
    if attachment.file
      return uploadAttachment(attachment)
    return
  return
```

**views/posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |form| %>
  <%= form.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= form.input :title %>
    <%= form.input :author_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: current_user.id } %>
    <%= form.input :body, as: :trix_editor %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= form.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have the same issues with trix editor. The image upload works fine for some time and then fails to load on subsequent calls of the page. Weird.

Comment: @ChidozieNnachor, yeah I've yet to figure this out.  I actually switch to another editor... but then had issue with it as well.  So since it was just a "fun" project I've moved to other ones in the meantime... but it's been awhile haha. Sorry I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: I have been checking around. I think my issue, which may be different from yours, relates to how I set the image to be cached both in development and in production. Since Heroku shuts down your database after some idle time, your images somehow can't be retrieved after. In essence, file storage using Shrine or Carrierwave or some other gem for both environments should be set up differently (most tutorials don't mention this). I am currently working on that.

Comment: This page explains more
https://shrinerb.com/rdoc/classes/Shrine/Storage/FileSystem.html